# Access 2013: Set value based on date

Tags: ms-access-2013

I want something rather simple (I think), but can't get it quite to work... 
Let me start by saying I am an absolute noob to Access, that doesn't help much either.

What I want is to have a checkbox (Yes/ No field) ticked if there is no end date (or the end date is in the future). If the end date is in the past, uncheck (Item not active anymore).

Should I use VBA for this, or would a query suffice?

Any pointers more then welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as ControlSource for the CheckBox an expression like this:

```
=DateDiff("d",Date(),Nz([EndDate],#12/31/9999#))>0
```

Comment: Hello Gustav! 
That works beautifully, I just tweaked the >0 to -1 to include today in the active period and works a charm.